# Binding brokes if I extract an input to a component - SvelteKit 1.0

Tags: binding, svelte

Reactivity and bindings that I set works perfectly when I bind variables to input elements directly, but when I refactor and extract those input to a components and bind values to then, doesn't work.

Given this data:

```
export let config = {
  attributes: {
    min: 4,
    max: 10,
  },
}

export let attributes = {
  physical: {
    label: 'Físico',
    value: config.attributes.min,
  },
  dexterity: {
    label: 'Destreza',
    value: config.attributes.min,
  },
  intelligence: {
    label: 'Inteligencia',
    value: config.attributes.min,
  },
  perception: {
    label: 'Percepción',
    value: config.attributes.min,
  },
}
```

And the extracted component, **Counter**:

```
<script>
  export let value = 0
  export let min = 0
  export let max = 0
  export let placeholder = ''
  export let name = ''
  export let label = ''

  function increment() {
    if (value < max) {
      value += 1
    }
  }

  function decrement() {
    if (value > min) {
      value -= 1
    }
  }
$: console.log(value)
</script>

<label class="field" for={name}>
  <span>{label}</span>
  <div>
    <input {name} {placeholder} type="number" {min} {max} bind:value />
    <button on:click={decrement}>-</button>
    <button on:click={increment}>+</button>
  </div>
</label>
```

Which is extracted from the main application

```
<script>
    import { attributes , config } from './data.js'
    import Counter from './Counter.svelte'
</script>

<section id="attributes">
  {#each Object.entries(attributes) as [key, { label, value }], index}
    <Counter
    {label}
    name={key}
    placeholder={label}
    min={config.attributes.min}
    max={config.attributes.max}
    bind:value
    />
<!-- Code below is the same as Counter -->
      <label class="field" for={name} >
    <span>{label}</span>
    <div>
      <input
        {label}
        name={key}
        placeholder={label}
        min={config.attributes.min}
        max={config.attributes.max}
        bind:value
      />
      <button on:click={() => {value -= 1}}>-</button>
      <button on:click={() => {value += 1}}>+</button>
    </div>
      </label>
<!-- Code above is the same as Counter -->
  {/each}
</section>
{#each Object.entries(attributes) as [key, { label, value }]}
  <p>{label}: {value}</p>
{/each}

<style>
    .field {
        background: MediumSeaGreen;
    }
</style>
```

I tried to put side by side code, and repl it, but luckless.

Problem representation is here, where green background inputs are binded and others don't.

I'm doing something wrong?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/68ffb825c1704c54802aa5be53379bec?version=3.57.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with invalidation. The value gets changed on the correct object, but the component is not notified correctly that `attributes` was affected.

I would not recommend using `Object.entries` when trying to mutate data. If you use `Object.keys` instead, you can make sure the connection between the change and `attributes` is picked up (though this might still potentially be a bug).

Example:

```html
{#each Object.keys(attributes) as key}
    <Counter
         label={attributes[key].label}
         name={key}
         placeholder={attributes[key].label}
         min={config.attributes.min}
         max={config.attributes.max}
         bind:value={attributes[key].value}
         />
{/each}
```

By the way:

- The `for` attributes targets the `id` of the input, not the `name`.
- You don't need `for` when the targeted input is within the `label`
- Having multiple interactive elements within a `label` is technically invalid

Comment: I really appreciate your time and response . I understand what you say and was one of my own alternatives to make this work. I'm still a little confused about this because Object.entries works when you don't have to deal with props and bind values directly.
Anyway, thank you again.
Pd: Thanks for the advice about HTML composition. This is a project in which i'm learning how Svelte works.